# MSBuild requiring DLL to be copied to BOTH .NET directory and current build directory

Tags: c#, .net, dll, msbuild

I'm not only looking for a cleaner way to do this, but also find out why what I'm currently doing works...

I'm using MSBuild (not Visual Studio, just Notepad++ and calling MSBuild via a command line). MSBuild requires a project file (just like Visual Studio) to guide the build process. As part of the build, I'm making a call to a C# file using .NET's `UsingTask` in the project file to make the appropriate changes to the database. This way I only need to run MSBuild when I install this on a new computer and the build will update the database for me.

The C# code uses a third party DLL. In order to access that DLL I need to copy it from a static location (e.g. `D:\ThirdParty\MyDLL.dll`) to the current build directory. That part's fine. The strange part is that it ***also*** needs me to copy the DLL to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. If I copy the DLL to *either* the current build directory *or* `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and not the other, then it won't build. If I copy it to *both* directories, only then will it work.

Here are the important parts of my code:

Defining the UsingTask

```
<UsingTask
    TaskName="UpdateDB"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup />
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Data" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
        <Reference Include="MyDLL.dll" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Using Namespace="MyDLL.Db.Foo" />
        <Code Type="Class" Language="cs" Source="UpdateDB.cs" />
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

Copy the DLL...

```
<Copy
        SourceFiles="D:\ThirdParty\MyDLL.dll"
        DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildToolsPath)"
    />
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="D:\ThirdParty\MyDLL.dll"
        DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
    />
```

Call the UsingTask defined above...

```
<UpdateDB />
```

So I'm wondering why I need to copy the DLL to both locations and not just one or the other.  I've tested this over and over again by removing the DLL from both directories and just copying it to one of them. It only works if I copy the DLL to both. Is there a cleaner way to do this, and if not, why does it work this way?

Comment: This is a pretty unproductive way to go about it.  Just find out how Visual Studio solves the problem, the Express edition is free so there are very few practical obstacles.  You'll have no trouble discovering the `<HintPath>` property.

Comment: @Hans - I've actually tried looking through Visual Studio project files as well using visual studio 2013. The HintPath doesn't work with UsingTasks.

Comment: @Adam, have you found a workaround? HintPath not working with UsingTasks is a bummer.

Comment: @vulcanraven - Unfortunately I'm still just copying it to both locations. It works fine this way but it's just not as clean as I'd hope, and I'd also like to know why it only works when I copy to both locations.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try this:-
Create one directory "libraries" under project directory
Copy third party dll to that folder

```
<Copy
    SourceFiles="D:\ThirdParty\MyDLL.dll"
    DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\libraries"
/>
```

Do not copy to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

And in task

```
<reference include="libraries\MyDll.dll">
```

And try to execute your program and let me know what happens

Comment: It shows the same error (can't find the DLL). I confirmed that DLL did in fact copy to the libraries directory noted above. I also ran it a second time just in case the copy was being done asynchronously.